# Prevent angular validation from occurring while entering data

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation

I have a form with an email field. I would like to prevent the user from submitting unless the email address exists and is valid. However, I only want these errors to appear when toggling out of the email field or clicking sumbit. My "invalid email" message is appearing WHILE the user is typing the email and remains visible until they've finished entering a valid email. How can I prevent this behavior?

```
        <div ng-show="emailMeForm.Email.$error.required" class="errorMessage">
            You must enter an email
        </div>

        <div ng-show="emailMeForm.Email.$error.email" class="errorMessage">
            Email address invalid
        </div>

        <form name="emailMeForm" novalidate="">
            Email Address
            <input ng-model="vm.emailAddress" type="email" name="Email" />
            <button ng-click="emailMeForm.$valid">Continue</button>
        </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Must be sufficient:

```
ng-show="emailMeForm.Email.$touched && emailMeForm.Email.$error.required"
```